Orico usb-case with SSD (4TB) ... fails ...?
I wonder if installation on to Orico USB-Case with built-in SSD (4TB) works ?
Probably Orico has an EFI/UEFI - Chip built-in ? Can this be ?
I tried with Solus 4.5 Budgie (seems to work), With Solus 4.5 GNOME (does not work) ...
it seems that attempt with installation got shot-off online ?!
Ubuntu seems to work but breaks off ... (though attempt was offline ?) ... ?
Does anybody know how to solve this ? (How to switch off UEFI/EFI - Chip if necessary ?)
Is this possible to install without bootloader ? (to avoid UEFI/EFI ?)

Which Ubuntu release are you trying to install?  What errors do you see?  An Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop installed flawlessly to an Orico NVME M.2 USB3 enclosure with a 256GB Hynix SSD, and runs like an internal SSD. efi partition on the SSD for UEFI.  What does lsusb -vv show for the  iproduct (RTL9210B-CG worked for me). UEFI chips I haven't heard of, bu you can certainly use the internal disk's EFI partition for your bootloaders. Hate to suggest it, but have you tried looking at the f3 package (fight fake flash).

Have seen several posts where users needed this: Not sure why. Some NVMe drives need this parameter in grub:
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0  I have two external drives one SSK and other fideco, both with smaller SSDs. Have seen others post using Orico adapters.

Hello ... thank you for answer ... I was trying this installation with 24.04 Desktop. @oldfred ... is this parameter helping in any case in grub ?: nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 ? Or is this parameter only for US-made SSDs ?! The SSD here in my USB-case is from China. But I re-try it with previous, which were successful ... I think it is related to USB and EFI/UEFI with grub. This problem was earlier already a topic ?!

There are US made SSDs? I have have seen several posts where users needed that parameter to stop issues with SSD drives.
